# My seat belt alarm/sounder no longer functions - 2004 Carolla

Tags: toyota, corolla, belt, alarm, seat

My 2004 Carolla seat belt alarm/sounder no longer sounds, but seat belt light on dash works fine (goes off when seat belt inserted).  Where is the sound/alarm located ?

This problem started after Toyota recalls installed by Dealer. Now Toyota USA says I must pay $125/hour to have dealer work on it.  They put six hours looking for problem, can't fix it so far.   Do not buy a Toyota.  I have two Toyota vehicles for sale now.

Comment: Please consider revising your question. It come across as though you are just bashing Toyota and not really interested in an answer.